# How to refactor this python code block to be more efficient

Tags: python

This code block works - it loops through a file that has a repeating number of sets of data 
and extracts out each of the 5 pieces of information for each set.

But I I know that the current factoring is not as efficient as it can be since it is looping 
through each key for each line found.

Wondering if some python gurus can offer better way to do this more efficiently.

```
def parse_params(num_of_params,lines):

  for line in lines:
    for p in range(1,num_of_params + 1,1):
      nam = "model.paramName "+str(p)+" "
      par = "model.paramValue "+str(p)+" "
      opt = "model.optimizeParam "+str(p)+" "
      low = "model.paramLowerBound "+str(p)+" "
      upp = "model.paramUpperBound "+str(p)+" "
      keys = [nam,par,opt,low,upp]
      for key in keys:
        if key in line:
          a,val = line.split(key)
          if key == nam: names.append(val.rstrip())
          if key == par: params.append(val.rstrip())
          if key == opt: optimize.append(val.rstrip())
          if key == upp: upper.append(val.rstrip())
          if key == low: lower.append(val.rstrip())

print "Names   = ",names   
print "Params   = ",params
print "Optimize = ",optimize
print "Upper    = ",upper
print "Lower    = ",lower
```

Comment: Could you perhaps give us some input data?

Comment: More efficient? You have to start by writing it in a sane, ordered fasion. Try simple code that works, not storing compound data in single strings. Often simply expressing the code better will give you all the "optimization" you need.

Answer (score 2):

Though this doesn't answer your question (other answers are getting at that) something that has helped me a lot in doing things similar to what you're doing are [List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). They allow you to build lists in a concise and (I think) easy to read way.

For instance, the below code builds a 2-dimenstional array with the values you're trying to get at.  `some_funct` here would be a little regex, if I were doing it, that uses the index of the last space in the key as the parameter, and looks ahead to collect the value you're trying to get in the line (the value which corresponds to the key currently being looked at) and appends it to the correct index in the seen_keys 2D array.

Wordy, yes, but if you get list-comprehension and you're able to construct the regex to do that, you've got a nice, concise solution.

```
keys = ["model.paramName ","model.paramValue ","model.optimizeParam ""model.paramLowerBound ","model.paramUpperBound "]
for line in lines:
    seen_keys = [[],[],[],[],[]]
    [seen_keys[keys.index(k)].some_funct(line.index(k) for k in keys if k in line]
```

Comment: List comprehensions are for simple expressions that fit on one line. It is not so in this case therefore explicit loop should be used. *Readability counts.*

Comment: That's definitely true – I'd still be tempted to be OK with this layer of abstraction, especially because the semantic representation list comprehension gives you can make up for a complicated use of it. But it's largely personal preference. I think it's good to err on the side of readability, though. No disagreement here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of duplication there, and if you ever add another `key` or `param`, you're going to have to add it in many places, which leaves you ripe for errors.  What you want to do is pare down all of the places you have repeated things and use some sort of data model, such as a `dict`.

Some others have provided some excellent examples, so I'll just leave my answer here to give you something to think about.

Answer (score 1):

It's not totally easy to see the expected format.  From what I can see, the format is like:

```
lines = [
    "model.paramName 1 foo",
    "model.paramValue 2 bar",
    "model.optimizeParam 3 bat",
    "model.paramLowerBound 4 zip",
    "model.paramUpperBound 5 ech",
    "model.paramName 1 foo2",
    "model.paramValue 2 bar2",
    "model.optimizeParam 3 bat2",
    "model.paramLowerBound 4 zip2",
    "model.paramUpperBound 5 ech2",
]
```

I don't see the above code working if there is more than one value in each line.   Which means the digit is not really significant unless I'm missing something.  In that case this works very easily:

```
import re

def parse_params(num_of_params,lines):
    key_to_collection = {
        "model.paramName":names,
        "model.paramValue":params,
        "model.optimizeParam":optimize,
        "model.paramLowerBound":upper,
        "model.paramUpperBound":lower,
    }

    reg = re.compile(r'(.+?) (\d) (.+)')

    for line in lines:
        m = reg.match(line)
        key, digit, value = m.group(1, 2, 3)
        key_to_collection[key].append(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely obvious from your code, but it looks like each line can have one "hit" at most; if that's indeed the case, then something like:

```
import re

def parse_params(num_of_params, lines):
  sn = 'Names Params Optimize Upper Lower'.split()
  ks = '''paramName paramValue optimizeParam
          paramLowerBound paramUpperBound'''.split()
  vals = dict((k, []) for k in ks)
  are = re.compile(r'model\.(%s) (\d+) (.*)' % '|'.join(ks))
  for line in lines:
    mo = are.search(line)
    if not mo: continue
    p = int(mo.group(2))
    if p < 1 or p > num_of_params: continue
    vals[mo.group(1)].append(mo.group(3).rstrip())
  for k, s in zip(ks, sn):
    print '%-8s =' % s,
    print vals[k]
```

might work -- I exercised it with a little code as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  lines = '''model.paramUpperBound 1 ZAP
    model.paramLowerBound 1 zap
    model.paramUpperBound 5 nope'''.splitlines()
  parse_params(2, lines)
```

and it emits

```
Names    = []
Params   = []
Optimize = []
Upper    = ['zap']
Lower    = ['ZAP']
```

which I think is what you want (if some details must differ, please indicate exactly what they are and let's see if we can fix it).

The two key ideas are: use a `dict` instead of lots of `if`s; use a `re` to match "any of the following possibilities" with parenthesized groups in the re's pattern to catch the bits of interest (the keyword after `model.`, the integer number after that, and the "value" which is the rest of the line) instead of lots of `if x in y` checks and string manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

The code given in the OP does multiple tests per line to try to match against the expected set of values, each of which is being constructed on the fly. Rather than construct `paramValue1`, `paramValue2`, etc. for each line, we can use a regular expression to try to do the matching in a cheaper (and more robust) manner.

Here's my code snippet, drawing from some ideas that have already been posted. This lets you add a new keyword to the `key_to_collection` dictionary and not have to change anything else.

```
import re

def parse_params(num_of_params, lines):

    pattern = re.compile(r"""
        model\.
        (.+)    # keyword
        (\d+)   # index to keyword
        [ ]+    # whitespace
        (.+)    # value
        """, re.VERBOSE)

    key_to_collection = {
        "paramName": names,
        "paramValue": params,
        "optimizeParam": optimize,
        "paramLowerBound": upper,
        "paramUpperBound": lower,
    }

    for line in lines:
        match = pattern.match(line)
        if not match:
            print "Invalid line: " + line
        elif match[1] not in key_to_collection:
            print "Invalid key: " + line
        # Not sure if you really care about enforcing this
        elif match[2] > num_of_params:
            print "Invalid param: " + line
        else:
            key_to_collection[match[1]].append(match[3])
```

Full disclosure: I have *not* compiled/tested this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that parse_params is the bottle-neck? Have you profiled your app?

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict 

names = ("paramName paramValue optimizeParam "
         "paramLowerBound paramUpperBound".split())
stmt_regex = re.compile(r'model\.(%s)\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)' % '|'.join(names))

def parse_params(num_of_params, lines):
    stmts = defaultdict(list)
    for m in (stmt_regex.match(s) for s in lines):
        if m and 1 <= int(m.group(2)) <= num_of_params: 
           stmts[m.group(1)].append(m.group(3).rstrip())

    for k, v in stmts.iteritems():
        print "%s = %s" % (k, ' '.join(v))
```

Answer (score 0):

It can certainly be made more efficient. But, to be honest, unless this function is called hundreds of times a second, or works on thousands of lines, is it necessary?

I would be more concerned about making it clear what is happening... currently, I'm far from clear on that aspect.

Just eyeballing it, the input seems to look like this:

**model.paramName 1 A model.paramValue 1 B model.optimizeParam 1 C model.paramLowerBound 1 D model.paramUpperBound 1 E model.paramName 2 F model.paramValue 2 G model.optimizeParam 2 H model.paramLowerBound 2 I model.paramUpperBound 2 J**

And your desired output seems to be something like:

```
Names     = AF
Params    = BG
etc...
```

Now, since my input certainly doesn't match yours, the output is likely off too, but I think I have the gist.

There are a few points. First, does it matter how many parameters are passed to the function? For example, if the input has two sets of parameters, do I just want to read both, or is it necessary to allow the function to only read one? For example, your code allows me to call `parse_params(1,1)` and have it only read parameters ending in a 1 from the same input. If that's not actually a requirement, you can skip a large chunk of the code.

Second, is it important to ONLY read the given parameters? If I, for example, have a parameter called 'paramFoo', is it bad if I read it? You can also simplify the procedure by just grabbing all parameters regardless of their name, and extracting their value.

```
def parse_params(input):
  parameter_list = {}
  param = re.compile(r"model\.([^ ]+) [0-9]+ ([^ ]+)")
  each_parameter = param.finditer(input)
  for match in each_parameter:
    key = match[0]
    value = match[1]
    if not key in paramter_list:
      parameter_list[key] = []

    parameter_list[key].append(value)

  return parameter_list
```

The output, in this instance, will be something like this:

{'paramName':[A, F], 'paramValue':[B, G], 'optimizeParam':[C, H], etc...}

Notes: I don't know Python well, I'm a Ruby guy, so my syntax may be off. Apologies.